# SQL JOIN WITH TWO WHERE CLAUSES

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I would like to implement the following SQL query : suppose using JOIN clause, due to now it's running quite slow:

```
SELECT ID_USER, NICK
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ID_USER IN 
(
    SELECT ID_INDEX1 
    FROM TABLE2 
    WHERE ID_INDEX2 = '2'
)
AND ID_USER NOT IN 
(
    SELECT ID_INDEX2 
    FROM TABLE2 
    WHERE ID_INDEX1 = '2' AND GO ='NO'
)
ORDER BY NICK ASC
```

Comment: If it has a lot of fields, you may check if selecting only the fields you need helps. `*` is overkill in th\e majority of situations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edit the query deleting the *. Any help?

Comment: hard to tell without execution plan and description of your tables (indexes, how many rows, unique constraints, ...)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you didn't mix up ID_INDEX1 and ID_INDEX2 in your IN clauses? Because in the first one, you use ID_INDEX1 to filter the user, whereas in the second one, you use ID_INDEX2.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the "including" part with `INNER JOIN` and the "excluding" part with a "LEFT JOIN" + filtering:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID_USER, t1.NICK
FROM TABLE1 t1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2IN
    ON t1.ID_USER = t2IN.ID_INDEX1
    AND t2IN.ID_INDEX2 = '2'
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2OUT
    ON t1.ID_USER = t2OUT.ID_INDEX2
    AND t2OUT.ID_INDEX1 = '2'
    AND t2OUT.GO = 'NO'
WHERE t2OUT.ID_INDEX IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.NICK ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to filter by `ID_INDEX1` in both cases (see my comment on your question), you can:

- count the number of rows per user in table2 with value = 2
- count the number of rows per user in table2 with value = 2 and go = 'NO'
- return only those for which the first count is greater than 0 and the second count equals 0

i.e.:

```
select * from (
  select 
    id_user,
    nick,
    sum(case when table2.id_index2 = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as count2_overall,
    sum(case when table2.id_index2 = '2' and go = 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) as count2_no
  from table1
  join table2 on table1.id_user = table2.id_index1
  group by id_user, nick
) 
where count2_overall > 0 and count2_no = 0
```